# Python Matplotlib scatter plot adding x-axis labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have this following code in order to generate scatterplots

```
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

              line = plt.figure()    
              plt.plot(xvalue, yvalue)
              plt.grid(True)
              plt.savefig("test.png")
              plt.show()
```

and here is the screenshot of the plot: 
[image]

I am just wondering if i could change the x-axis labels into strings. I have stored all the labels in

```
    xlabel = ['2015/4/1', '2015/4/11', '2015/4/12', '2015/4/18', '2015/4/19'...]
```

Is there any function for matplotlib so that i could set x-axis labels to the values in "xlabel"?

many thx!

ALso my labels are overlapped, anything i could do to fix this problem? thx!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my answer.  You target was to plot the datetime as xticklabel.
I always do something like this. Code like this:

```
## For example, I have 9 daily value during 2013-04-01 to 2014-04-10
start = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-04-2013", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("10-04-2013", "%d-%m-%Y")
date = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
## y is the data I want to plot
ind = np.arange(len(y))
ax=plt.subplot()
plt.plot(ind,y,lw = 3)
k = []
for i in range(0,len(ind),1):
    k.append(str(date[i])[0:10])

plt.xticks(ind,k,rotation=65)
```

[image]

#### Update

To solve the overlap problem, I recommend the code below:

```
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

For daily value in a month, you can get a figure like this:

[image]

Comment: thx for the thorough answer! exactly waht i want for the overlapping issue!

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
plt.xticks(xs, labels)
```

Where `xs` is a list of the positions for the ticks, and `labels` is the list of labels.

Comment: sorry about pressing the enter button by accident. my labels are overlapped, is there anyway to fix this? thx!

Comment: i did try plt.xticks(xvalue, dates,rotation=45) and 
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05). but they are not working so well. thx for the help!

Comment: i have solved the problem of overlapping with other's answer. Thx for the xticks thing!